# How to list dynamic and Compile-time variables in Raku

Tags: raku, introspection

In Raku, how can I list:

1. [Dynamic variables](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#Dynamic_variables)
2. [Compile time variables](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#Compile-time_variables)
3. [Packages](https://docs.raku.org/language/packages#Pseudo-packages)
4. [Pseudo packages](https://docs.raku.org/language/packages#Pseudo-packages)

To list lexical variables in scope, I use `say ::;` and [Pseudo packages](https://docs.raku.org/language/packages#Pseudo-packages).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, generally.

### Dynamic variables

I guess technically you could devise a pad walker routine that would check all of the pads to see if there was a dynamic variable defined in a pad and create a list of it.  But some dynamic variables don't actually exist until they're actually used, e.g. `$*DISTRO` (which lives in the `PROCESS::` namespace if it was referenced):

```
say PROCESS::<$DISTRO>:exists;  # False
$*DISTRO;  # just need to refer to it
say PROCESS::<$DISTRO>:exists;  # True
```

### Compile time variables

Compile time variables generally only exist at compile time and are generally codegenned as a constant.  A prime example of  that is `$?LINE`, which has a value dependent on the line in your code.

### Packages

Packages can be lexically (`my`) scoped, or `OUR::` scoped.  And as such, they can be found.  The big problem with descending into subclasses is that Rakudo is an irresponsible parent.  A package knows of its parent classes, but not the other way around.

### Pseudo packages

The `PseudoStash` class contains an internal data structure that contains the names of all the possible pseudo packages, but that is not externally available.  I guess it could be made that way.

### Conclusion

Perhaps a more directed question about why you would want the information, would give a better, more useful answer?

Comment: "Rakudo is an irresponsible parent" — thanks lizmat++ for the smile today

Comment: Thanks ! For the use : it is to get completion in [p6-jupyter-kernel](https://github.com/bduggan/p6-jupyter-kernel/blob/f70da7d51f22dc4926bc9c463ef3cf65b575fa9a/lib/Jupyter/Kernel/Sandbox/Autocomplete.rakumod#L67-L71) when user types `$*` or `$?` which gives a fast lookup when developing.

Comment: I wonder how Comma solves that?  I guess they keep a list somewhere?